# How to call one class output from another class function in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, function, class, object

I have difficulty calling one class function output in another class. Below is the sample block of the code:

```
import pandas as pd

# First Class
class ppl():
    def create_ppl(self):
        ppll_info = pd.DataFrame({
            'Name':['Bob','Amy'],
            'Age':[12,19],
            'Gender':['male','female']
        })

instructor_info = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name_Inst':['Tobby','John'],
                 'Age':[41,37],
                 'Gender':['male','male']
})
pl = ppl()
pl.create_ppl()

# second Class
class robot():
    def create_rbt(self):
        rbt_info = pd.DataFrame({
            'Name':['Robot_1','Robt_2'],
            'Manufacture':['ABC','XYZ'],
            'Owner':['Bob','Amy']
        })

        full_table = pd.merge(
            rbt_info,
            pl.create_ppl(),
            left_on='Owner',
            right_on='Name', how='left'
        )

        return full_table

rbt = robot()
rbt.create_rbt()
```

I received the error `TypeError: Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'NoneType'> was passed` 
It will work if I add `return ppll_info`  to the end of the first class. Because my actual output dataframe is really large and I don't want to return the output. Is there any more elegant way to do so?

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: Why are you using classes? You don't use a constructor nor any attributes. I like classes but don't use them if all you have is a single function.  Also `return` just returns the reference to the object. What do you want to accomplish exactly?

Comment: As I said, this is a sample class. My real class has multiple functions in it and I'd like to call the output from one of the functions.